# Como ver base de datos local mediante internet

Tags: android, php, html5, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo una base de datos local en mi casa con MS Sql Server, de esta base de datos solo necesito mostrar un dato de una tabla mediante internet o una aplicación, quisiera saber cual es la manera mas facil de lograr esto, para ejemplificar, si en la base de datos local se suma algo mas a el total, que ese total se muestre en la aplicación. Si en la base de datos la columna "total" cambia de 10 a 20 que ese 20 se muestre en la aplicación.

Comment: Bueno, no entiendo muy bien, deberías separar mejor la idea, pero según entiendo quieres mostrar un dato a través de una aplicacion, pero también quieres saber, si ya anteriormente en la aplicacion habian datos almacenados, dime si es asi

Comment: Solo quiero mostrar un dato en la aplicación. Lo unico que mostrara la aplicación es un total, que vendria siendo una columna en la base de datos que hay en mi casa.

Comment: Bueno dime si puedes poner la base de datos en un servidor como tal y los servicios??

Comment: La base de datos esta en una computadora que actua como servidor, esta se llena con un software de ventas que esta en otra computadora que actua como un punto de venta. En cuanto a los servicios no estoy muy claro a que te refieres

Comment: Bueno, me refiero a las APIs que desarrollas para interactuar entre el front y el back, a eso me refiero, veo que has hecho el proyecto todo de manera local, y pues según entiendo quieres utilizar una aplicacion móvil, dime si estoy equivocado en el sentido que quieres usar internet con tu proyecto?

Comment: Si, solo quisiera ver el total de las ventas de la tienda desde una aplicación no quiero modificar, ni añadir datos solo visualizar los totales pero de manera remota

Comment: Hola, creo que has preguntado lo mismo o parecido en [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/9321/602) otra pregunta que está en espera. Cuando una pregunta se pone en espera no hay que añadir una nueva pregunta sino mejorar la pregunta para que sea reabierta y respondida. A esta pregunta le pasa lo mismo, tiene muchas respuestas posibles y lo mas probable se se vuelva a cerrar. Deberías aportar mas detalles para que esto no pase o si pasa, que se vuelva a reabrir.

Comment: Upps, se ha puesto en espera y creo que por mi culta. Como te decía deberías aportar más detalles para que se reabra y sea respondida. Por cierto,  ¿eres desarrollador? ¿con que tecnologías trabajas?.  También le podrías echar un vistazo a [Zappier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/sql-server/) porque permite de forma sencilla integrar aplicaciones permitiéndote por ejemplo sincronizar una tabla de SQL Server en una hoja de cálculo de Google. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es acceder de manera remota a tu base de datos, tienes que tener una ip publica, de preferencia estática para que puedas conectar al servicio que quieres sin perder la conexión, ademas debes abrir los puertos en el router, por ejemplo para conectar a mysql tendrías que abrir el puerto 3306. Si quieres usar una aplicación web para mostrar los resultados podrías levantar un server apache y hacerlo publico mediante tu router. En el siguiente enlace tienes un ejemplo de como levantar un servidor web desde tu casa

http://www.muycomputer.com/2014/08/05/montar-servidor-web